# Installing geoserver along jetty on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jetty, geoserver

Is there any simple tutorial for installing **geoserver** with **jetty** on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Did you read Geoserver [install docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux/index.html)? It says that the binary download is a bundle of geoserver with jetty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unzip openjdk-6-jre

echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.3.5/geoserver-2.3.5-bin.zip/download

unzip -a geoserver-2.3.5-bin.zip

cd geoserver-2.3.5/bin

./startup.sh &
```

In web browser visit http://localhost:8080/geoserver/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/winsent/geoserver/ it based on Oracle Java 7 with JAI 1.1.3, ImageIO 1.1, GDAL 1.10.1 and extensions.

Or see Dockerfile how to install https://hub.docker.com/r/winsent/geoserver/~/dockerfile/

Answer (score 0):

You can use abhijeetkoli/geoserver image if you wish to give it a try.

Source and build scripts are [here](https://github.com/avkoli/kubernetes-gis/tree/master/scripts/docker/geoserver)

**Docker**

```sh
docker run -d --name geoserver abhijeetkoli/geoserver
```

**Kubernetes**

```sh
kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/gis.config apply  \
    -f ./scripts/kubernetes/gis/geoserver-service.yaml \
    -f ./scripts/kubernetes/gis/geoserver-deployment.yaml
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.